# TCPIP illustrated volume1 delayed acknowledge in TCP

Tags: networking, tcp

I am reading TCP/IP Illustrated volume 1 about TCP Interactive flow

> If we look at the time differences between bsdi receiving the data and
>   sending the ACK, they appear to be random: 123.5, 65.6, 109.0,
>   132.3,42.0, 140.3, and 195.8 ms.Look instead at the actual times (starting from 0) when the ACKs are sent: 139.9, 539.9,940.1, 1339.9,
>   1739.9, 1940.1, and 2140.1 ms. (We have marked these with an asterisk to the left of the time in Figure 19.3.) There is a multiple of 200 ms
>   between these times.What is happening here is that TCP has a timer
>   that goes off every 200 ms, but it goes off at fixed points in
>   time-every 200 ms relative to when the kernel was bootstrapped. Since
>   the data being acknowledged arrives randomly (at times 16.4, 474.3,
>   831.1, etc.), TCP asks to be notified the next time the kernel's 200-ms timer expires. This can be anywhere from 1 to 200 ms in the
>   future.

My question is

1. What does author mean "139.9, 539.9,940.1, 1339.9, 1739.9, 1940.1, and 2140.1 ms" are mutliple of 200 ms between these times?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly that. If you calculate the differences between the times, the results will be (almost) multiples of 200ms.

Comment: `539.9 - 139.9 = 400 = 200 x 2`